# Error in atom package installer, displaying searching failed

Tags: package, atom-editor

Searching for <package_name> failed.Hide output…

i.filter is not a function
[object Object]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mRwre.png)

Answer (score 1):

The servers are having issues today (I ran into the same problem). On linux you can install from command line using

```
apm install <package-name>
```

apm is the Atom package manager. Other OS' probably have equivalents.